# Django Apps aren't loaded yet: How to import models

Tags: django

I have a Django project looking like

```
> project
    > gui
        > __init__.py
        > models.py
        > views.py
        > ...
    > project
        __init__.py
        ...
```

I am trying to sync the sqllite db in django with some info I periodically query from other sources. So in project.**init**.py I spawn a thread that periodically queries data.
However, I am having trouble accessing my models from there and update the database, because when I try to import them into **init**.py

```
from gui.models import GuiModel
```

I get

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Is there a trick to do that or a different way to create a separate thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Django Official Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage), If you’re using components of Django “standalone” you should follow something like this,

```
import sys
import os
import django

sys.path.append("/path/to/project")  # here project is root folder(means parent).
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "store.settings")
django.setup()

from gui.models import GuiModel

# do something here with models
```

Comment: thanks, that works. Actually, it appears that with that folder structure, all it takes is to run django.setup()

Answer (score 1):

If you send all details correctly, I think you have a circular import in your code. simple way is to to move import into your function.

also you can create a custom command in your project and add a cronjob to your server to do this works.